# Rsync through reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, rsync

I currently have a working reverse ssh tunnel setup which allows me to remote into a cell network module-connected raspberry pi from a wifi-connected home desktop using port forwarding. While I can now freely ssh into the cellular connected raspi, using Rsync for file transfer to that cellular raspi is not working. Here are the commands I have used:

First, on cellular raspi (4000 = ssh port on raspi, 5000 = ssh port on desktop):

```
ssh -f -N -T -R 2222:localhost:4000 desktop_username@routerip -p 5000
```

Next, on desktop:

```
rsync -avr -e "ssh -p 2222" /source_dir raspi_username@localhost:/target_dir
```

this results in the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

I know for a fact that ssh is functioning as I can remote back into the raspi from desktop following the first command up above via:

```
ssh raspi_username@localhost -p 2222
```

What corrections should I make to use Rsync properly in this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging that you are able to ssh into you machine on port 2222, I think you have the remote port (desktop) mixed up with the port (2222). Try the following on you Raspberry Pi:

```
ssh -f -N -T -R 5000:localhost:4000 desktop_username@routerip -p 2222
```